# Excel Nested Function

Tags: excel, if-statement

i'm trying to write an if statement with nested functions that states if a the value in column d is "CDRN PORTAL PROSPECT" or the date in column m plus 90 days or the date in column l plus 90 days is greater than or equal to the date in cell x1, then take the dollar value from column w otherwise it is zero. however, the formula seems to work for some cells but not others. can someone help? here is the formula as it is written:

```
=IF(AND($D3="CDRN Portal Prospect",($M3+90)>=X$1,($L3+90)>=X$1),$W3,0)
```

Comment: Based on your explanation, shouldn't you be using the OR() function instead of AND()? `=IF(OR($D3="CDRN Portal Prospect",($M3+90)>=X$1,($L3+90)>=X$1),$W3,0)`

Comment: thanks for responding! i tried using the or and also nesting both and/or but it still doesn't seem to be working. do you have any other ideas on what i can be doing wrong? what's really confusing is that it works for some cells and not others. for example, if one of the dates in column M goes back past 11/1/15 and the date in X1 is 4/1/16 and the value is column D does not equal CDRN portal prospect, I would assume that the logic would hold true and the cell with this formula would populate with the value in cell W. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Just checking, based on this last comment - are you trying to have it pull in cell W if column M or column L is MORE than 90 days prior to X1?...If, so you need to flip your operators to <=X1.

Comment: Otherwise, please try to post an example of a couple rows of your data or a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: how did you make sure that the date cells contain dates and not text plz?